# Run Python on Notepad++, execute screen

Tags: python, notepad++

https://medium.com/never-too-late-to-machine-learn/how-to-step-by-step-setup-notepad-to-run-python-scripts-e1ce3b3ac7fe

I am reading from this tutorial linked above.

What I am doing is trying to run python for the first time on Notepad++. I've downloaded python, etc.

What I am lost on is this:

"Just copy the location of the python exe file, and let’s go back to Notepad++. The execute screen is waiting for us.
In the execute screen, paste the location of Python followed with “$(FILE_NAME)” "

What is the execute screen, where am I pasting the location to?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Ask the author of the tutorial.

Comment: Please use a full-fledged IDE, e.g. Spyder, PyCharm, VSCode. Notepad++ it's just a handy tool to open and edit quickly files.

Answer (score 1):

to run your python script in notepad++ is quite simple:

0. make sure your python is correctly installed, open your console and type python, you should see something similar to the following (it should say *Python X.Y.Z* accordingly to the version you have installed) [image: step 0]

- 

1. now that we know that python is correctly installed, go to notepad++, open on it your desire script and go to the **Run** menu and select **Run...** [image: step 1]

- 

2. enter the following command `python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and press **Run** [image: step 2]

You should see the following [image: step 2 result]
And that is all.

-

3. Now that the previous worked, lets make it more reusable, repeat step 1 and 2, but instead of *Run* press **Save...**, give it a name (like python for example) and if you so desire also a keyboard binding (a key combination to press to run this command) [image: step 3]

Now in step 1, you can pick python (or whatever you name it) instead or "Run..." to run you script (or press you key combination if you give it one) [image]

---

now some additional explanation about the previous command `python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

- the `-i` option is to enter in interactive mode, that is run you script and then continue executing python so you can do more python stuff with everything for your script loaded in there too, that way the console doesn't just close intermediately after your script is done running.
- `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` is a command for notepad++ to said to substitute there for the full path of your given script

**Alternative command**: `cmd /K CD "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python -i "$(FILE_NAME)"`

This command is the equivalent to opening your console (`cmd /K`), move with `cd` to the folder where your script is (`CD "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"`) and then run your script with python in interactive mode (`python -i "$(FILE_NAME)"`) and & is to separate both instructions (the `/K` is like python's `-i` but for the console) (the "-i" is now optional, but I prefer it with it to test other stuff in the script without need to put it on the script because doing so make little sense...)

Why you might want to use this over the other? two reason:

1. the first is when dealing files so you don't have to type the full path of a given file that sit next to your script so you can use just the name of said file, aka set the working directory to that where the script is located, otherwise it will be that where notepad++ is located (usually it might be like "C:\Program Files\Notepad++").
2. In case of an error, the windows will remain open so you can know what was the error instead of closing abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` for full path of file, the `$(FILE_NAME)` is for file name only or relative path

then you can paste like

```
C:\Python39\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

for `execute screen`, new name for the menu is `Execute NppExec Script..` see image below

[image]

Comment: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases. I got this error.

I found the location and put the file name after like "$(Run_Python)"

Comment: I tried to do what it said but i have no luck with it right now.

Comment: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). (for using where python)

this is the new error. after doing what it said to do (uncheck those things in the microsoft store)

Comment: is python normally an .exe? mines like an application.

Comment: python is an .exe, download and install on https://www.python.org/downloads/ after installed do `where python`

Comment: yes, I did where python but it does not find it.